# Progress bar not visible for published app (RStudio)

Tags: shiny, rstudio, progress

I'm currently working on a modeling app in RStudio (my first project in R). When I run the app, the progress bar works perfectly and can be seen at the top of the page. For the published version online, however, it can't be seen. Any ideas as to what could be wrong? Thanks!

**edit**

This is the portion of the code with the progress bar:

```
withProgress(message="Computing", value=1,{
for (time in 2:N){

## various computations

incProgress(1/time,detail=paste("Doing simulation 1, timestep", time))
}
})
```

There is an identical progress bar for another computation later on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your code that demonstrates the problem? See here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure! Just added it.

Comment: add 'N=10' before the for loop or some other number as per example here http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: @pops thank you!! There's still an issue with the published version though. For some reason the bar just isn't showing up (but like I said, it works when the app is run through the program.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a known issue that has been fixed recently.

https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/20